# How to change colors of label and background with a button in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a button which can change the background colour along with the label background color and the background color. I have created a dictionary and a key for a dictionary and no matter what i do i cant seem to get it right.

I tried to use a def function to return a new key however, it does not return it

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import choice


MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE = 60
MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE = -100
HOT_TEMPERATURE = 30
COLD_TEMPERATURE = 0
DEFAULT_TOP_TEMPERATURE = "Please input the temperatures first"
DEFAULT_LOCATION = "Please input the locations first"


widget_assist = {"content" : 0, "input_box" : 1, "button" : 2, "combobox" : 3, "heading" : 4}
user_travel_history = {}

class Set_Widgets:
    def __init__(self, widget, text, position, background, pady = (0, 0), padx = (0, 0), font = "Arial", size = 10, width = 10, command = "", values = (), focus = False, type = "default"):
        self._widget = widget
        self._text = text
        self._position = position
        self._pady = pady
        self._padx = padx
        self._font = font
        self._size = size
        self._background = background
        self._width = width
        self._command = command
        self._values = values
        self._focus = focus
        self._type = type
        self._widget_object = None

        if (self._widget == widget_assist["content"]):
            self._widget_object = Label(root, text=self._text, background= self._background, font=(self._font, self._size))
        elif (self._widget == widget_assist["heading"]):
            self._widget_object = Label(root, text=self._text, background= self._background, font=("Helvetica", self._size, 'bold'))
        elif (self._widget == widget_assist["input_box"]):
            self._widget_object = Entry(root, width=self._width)
            if (focus):
                self._widget_object.focus()
        elif (self._widget == widget_assist["button"]):
            self._widget_object = Button(root, text=self._text, command=self._command)
        elif (self._widget == widget_assist["combobox"]):
            self._widget_object = Combobox(root, state="readonly")
            self._widget_object['values'] = values
            self._widget_object.current(0)

        self._widget_object.grid(column=position[0], row=position[1], pady=pady, padx=padx)

    def get_input(self):
        if (self._widget == widget_assist["content"]):
            return self._text
        elif (self._widget == widget_assist["input_box"] or self._widget == widget_assist["combobox"]):
            return self._widget_object.get()

    def change_text(self, text):
        self._widget_object.configure(text=text)


    def delete(self):
        self._widget_object.grid_remove()


class Information:
    def __init__(self, location, temperature):
        self._location = location
        self._temperature = temperature

    def get_location(self):
        return self._location

    def get_temp(self):
        return self._temperature



def converter(value, not_fahrenheit):
    try:
        value = round(float(value), 1)
    except ValueError:
        print("This functions works for only integers")
        return

    if (not_fahrenheit):
       return round(float(str(((value * 9/5) + 32))), 1)
    else:
        return round(float(str(((value - 32) * 5/9))), 1)

def submit(places):
    if (location_input.get_input() == "" or temp_input.get_input() == ""):
        messagebox.showinfo("Please complete all boxes.")
        return
    try:
        temperature = float(temp_input.get_input())
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showinfo('Please fill the boxes correctly (Use text for temperatures)')
        return

    if (location_input.get_input().isdigit() == True):
        messagebox.showinfo('Please fill the boxes correctly (Use text for locations)')
        return

    default_value = units.get_input()

    if (default_value == "fahrenheit"):
        temperature = converter(temperature, False)

    if (temperature > MAXIMUM_TEMPERATURE):
        messagebox.showinfo("This temperature is over the Max Temperature (Please type something lower than 60 degrees celsius)")
        return
    elif (temperature < MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE):
        messagebox.showinfo("This temperature is under the Min Temperature (Please type a value highter than -100 degrees celsius)")
        return

    travel_information = Information(location_input.get_input(), temperature)
    user_travel_history[travel_information.get_location()] = travel_information

    display = ""
    highest_temp = MINIMUM_TEMPERATURE
    top_temp_location = None

    for key, value in user_travel_history.items():
        display += value.get_location().title() + "\n" + str(value.get_temp()) + " C | " + str(converter(value.get_temp(), True)) + " F" + "\n\n"

        if (value.get_temp() > highest_temp):
            highest_temp = value.get_temp()
            top_temp_location = key



    places.change_text(display)
    top_temp_location_text.change_text(top_temp_location.title() + "\n" + str(highest_temp) + " C | " + str(converter(highest_temp, True)) + " F")

def remove_info():
    user_travel_history.clear()
    places.change_text(DEFAULT_LOCATION)
    top_temp_location_text.change_text(DEFAULT_TOP_TEMPERATURE)

def colorchange():
    colour_variable = "cold"
    return colour_variable

root = Tk()
root.title("Temporature Convertion Program")
root.geometry("360x720")
root.resizable(0,0)
colour = {"default" : "#FFFFFF", "cold" : "#ABD1F3", "hot" : "#CE2029"}
colour_variable = "default"

title = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["heading"], "Temperature Conversion", [0, 0], colour[colour_variable], pady=(10, 0), padx =(3, 0), size=22)
#sub_title = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], "Cool", [0, 1], colour[colour_variable], pady=(10, 10), size=15)

location_text = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], "Where did you visit: ", [0, 2], colour[colour_variable])
location_input = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["input_box"], None, [0, 3], colour["default"], pady=(0, 10), focus=True, width=25)

temp_text = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], "What was your temperature: ", [0, 4], colour[colour_variable])
temp_input = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["input_box"], None, [0, 5], colour["default"], pady=(0, 10))

units_text = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], "Temperature:", [0, 6], colour[colour_variable])
units = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["combobox"], None, [0, 7], colour["default"], values=('celsius', 'fahrenheit'))

submit_button = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["button"], "Add to diary", [0, 8], colour[colour_variable], pady=(20, 20), command=lambda: submit(places))

diary_text = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], "Places I've been to:", [0, 9], colour[colour_variable], pady=(0, 10), size=15)
places = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], DEFAULT_LOCATION, [0, 10], colour[colour_variable], pady=(0, 10))

hottest_place_title = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], "Hottest Place:", [0, 11], colour[colour_variable], pady=(0, 10), size=15)
top_temp_location_text = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["content"], DEFAULT_TOP_TEMPERATURE, [0, 12], colour[colour_variable], pady=(0, 10))


delete_button = Set_Widgets(widget_assist["button"], "Delete all records", [0, 13], colour[colour_variable], pady=(20, 0), command=remove_info)


if temperature > 30:
    colour_variable = "cold"
elif temperature < 30:
    colour_variable = "hot"
else:
    colour_variable = "default"

colour = {"default" : "#FFFFFF", "cold" : "#ABD1F3", "hot" : "#CE2029"}
root.configure(background=colour[colour_variable])

root.mainloop()
```

The fllowing is the dictionary and the key, I want to be able to freely use a button to change the label color.
Would there be any better ways to do this?

```
colour = {"default" : "#FFFFFF", "cold" : "#ABD1F3", "hot" : "#CE2029"}
colour_variable = "default"
```

Comment: You can change the options of any tkinter widget using the universal [`config()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. To implement what you want, create a callback function that uses it to change the configuration options of the widget you want to change, and specify that function as the `command=` option for the `Button` that's going to cause the change(s) to occur when its clicked.

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. There's a lot of code which looks unrelated to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

put a trace on your temperature variable that triggers a function when it changes.

```
def updateColour(*args):
    #your temp based color selection
    if temperature > 30:
        colour_variable = "cold"
    elif temperature < 30:
        colour_variable = "hot"
    else:
        colour_variable = "default"
    #then change the colors in the stuff you want 
    #below fg is text color, bg background color
    label.config(fg =colour[colour_variable], bg = colour[colour_variable])
    root.configure(background=colour[colour_variable]) 

temperature.trace("w", updateColour)
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much, where do you think I should put this function and how would i use it?

Comment: just add the updateColour function in where you have your functions and the trace should go after the temperature variable is defined, it looks like you do this in your 'submit' function block. Another option you have is to just to call the updateColour function from inside submit function (which is triggered when you press 'submit_button), with this the trace is not needed.